# Can't Center an Image

Tags: html, css

I've been reading various posts on stackoverflow and a few other sites about centering images.  I found this code on various sites that seems to be a general guide:

```
img  {
display: block;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
     }
```

I am trying to center an image.  I can't center it with this code.  I can make it move using text-align: center but read this isn't the best method of doing so.  I made a jsfiddle.  If anyone wouldn't mind helping me it would be appreciated.  I was able to make the image move as well by adding a random width value.  I don't think this is the right approach though either since I am eyeballing if it is centered or not.

Sorry, I couldn't get the actual image to display but the img logo is there as a placeholder: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sdaless/kTn7j/8/)

Comment: There's not a single image in your jsFiddle..

Comment: it works just fine on my end http://jsbin.com/uxalix/1/edit

Comment: `display block` & `margin left/right auto`, must be enough to center the img... in a **clean code** Take a look to YOUR example code here: http://jsfiddle.net/4cKFK/. The reason that's not working, for sure relies in something else in the code that is affecting the image the `img` tag or the image container. So, give us more information/code to work with and try to help you (your fiddle dosen't have any image).

Comment: Hey sorry all, I posted the jsfiddle before updating. I'm looking over all the suggestions now. Thanks for all the input. I updated the jsfiddle link above with an image. Thanks all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should work just fine. There's probably something more you're not showing us. Here's a demo of two methods, though.

Basically, if the img is `display: block;` you can use `margin: 0 auto`.

If it's `display: inline` (the default for an img tag) the parent element would need `text-align: center;` on it.

Here's some code to summarize: http://jsbin.com/upuzav/1/edit

Answer (score 0):

I would assign your image a class rather that trying to center all images with html.  This way if you want to change where its positioned, you can quickly, rather that adjusting all things with the img tag.

CSS:

```
.center_image {
display: block;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto }
```

Your Image:

```
<img src="your_image.jpg" class="center_image">
```

Answer (score 0):

In order for this trick to work the image **must** have an explicit width. See http://designshack.net/articles/css/how-to-center-anything-with-css/